# Please specify node.js interpreter correctly WebStorm error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I'm trying to simply create a `React Native` project via `Webstorm` but I get this error upon trying to do so which's resulting in myself not being able to start a project.

[image]

Whenever I do choose a `Node interpreter` it gives me an error that says `Unspecified react-native cli package` at the same spot that says `Please specify node.js interpreter correctly`.

I've been starting `React Native` projects like this since the beginning but this time I get this error out of no where, I don't know where it came from.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Opens up your terminal, and use the `which` command to find our your NodeJS interpreter

```
$ which node
/Users/felixfong/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node
```

And copy that result, and update your `Node interpreter` field inside yoru WebStorm

Hopes this help

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting an error at the same spot that says  `Unspecified react-native cli package`.  How would I get passed this?

Comment: `$ npm install -g react-native-cli && which react-native` and then copy the result | The response you get that error is because you didn't install the React Native CLI on your computer